# Problem with system $\dot x = 2x + y +e^t; \dot y = -2x + 2t$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am solving system of differential equations, 
$$
\begin{cases}
\dot x = 2x + y +e^t; \\
\dot y = -2x + 2t.
\end{cases}
$$
It's matrix, eigenvalues and eigenvectors are as follows:

$\qquad A = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ -2 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, \qquad \lambda_{12} = 1 \pm i, \qquad V_1 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ i - 1\end{pmatrix}, \qquad V_2 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ -i -1\end{pmatrix}$.

Thus, the solution is 
$$
X_0 = e^{(1+i)t}\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ i-1 \end{pmatrix} = e^t (\cos t+ i \sin t)\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ i-1 \end{pmatrix} = \\ e^t \begin{pmatrix} \cos t \\ -\cos t - \sin t \end{pmatrix}+i e^t \begin{pmatrix} \sin t \\ \cos t - \sin t \end{pmatrix}.
$$
And for each variable it yields 
\begin{cases}
x_0 = C_1 e^t \cos t + C_2 e^t \sin t; \\
y_0 = C_1 e^t ( -\cos t - \sin t ) + C_2 e^t (\cos t - \sin t). 
\end{cases}
When I diffepentiate it and plug into original system, I get wrong answer. But I can already see it is not right. The textbook says, the answer for homogenous system must be 
$$
\begin{cases}
x_0 = C_2 e^t \sin t+ C_1 e^t (\sin t+\cos t); \\
y_0 = C_2 e^t (\cos t-\sin t)-2 C_1 e^t \sin t
\end{cases}
$$
or 
$$
X_0 = 
C_1 e^t \begin{pmatrix} \sin t+\cos t \\ -2 \sin t \end{pmatrix}+
C_2 e^t \begin{pmatrix} \sin t \\ \cos t-\sin t \end{pmatrix}
$$
Where is my mistake? Thank you in advance.

Comment: $A = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ -2 & 0 \end{pmatrix};$
$|A -\lambda E| = \begin{pmatrix} 1-i & 1 \\ -2 & -1 - i \end{pmatrix}$ then from the first line (lines are dependent) $ x_1 = \alpha, x_2 = (i-1) \alpha \Rightarrow V_1 = (1, i-1)$

Comment: When I tried that one, it worked, but how can the answer depend on the vector I chose?

Answer (score 0):

probally it 'swrong after

> 'And for each variable it yields '

$X_0$ is a solution of 
$$
\begin{cases}
\dot x = 2x + y; \\
\dot y = -2x .
\end{cases}
$$
So $C_1 X_0 $ is also a solution but not $C_1 Re(X_0) + C_2 Im(X_0) $

You have to find the second solution $X_1$ with the second eigen value and so $C_1 X_0 + C_2 X_1 $ will be a solution

Comment: I suspect the $X_0$ itself, but do not know how to fix it, if the mistake is there